google api admin SDK and admin rights
I am coding a feature which retrieves the list of resources of my organization. I had admin rights for a while to create meeting rooms and my admin rights were taken away.  But when I try to retrieve the list of resources with new tokens with this scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar.readonly',
and using the command:
const admin = google.admin('directory_v1');
const response = await admin.resources.calendars.list({
    auth: auth,
    customer: 'my_customer',
}); 

I have no permissions problem and I recover my list.
My question: Can I use this scope and this command without being an admin or is there a particular reason for this to work in my case?
